IS there a way to update expired client secret for Enterprise Application in Azure Portal
I have an application registered in the Azure Portal that has been converted into an Enterprise application. The client secret for this application has expired, and I need to update it. However, since it has become an Enterprise application, I'm unable to find the option to perform this action.
Question:
How can I update the expired client secret for an Enterprise application?

Go to App registrations -> search your app -> certificates and secret blade. Check if you can find your application

I am not able to find my app in App Registrations, as it is enterprise app now\

So how did you create the old client secret?

It is done using app registration , how we generally do, but not its not available there. And hence I am not able to update the client secret

Did you try  searching the app in All applications instead if owned applications?

Yes it is, I have tried searching in all applications but could not find it

Maybe you created application in another tenant not in the tenant you are trying to search

I am able to search in the Azure Search box and it populates

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


Note that: The app registration of the Microsoft Entra ID application resides in the tenant where the application is created.


Only the service principal instance of the application will be created in other tenants.

I created a Microsoft Entra application in TenantA:

In another tenant when user sign-ins or creates service principal manually, the service principal of the application gets created:
When searched in TenantB, with the application name I got the service principal same as you:

Hence to know which tenant the application multi-tenant application is registered; you can use the below command:
Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "AppID" | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5



You can check  AppOwnerOrganizationId  which is the service principal app home tenant.

To update the client secret, check the home tenant of the service principal and login to the home tenant and update.

Thanks rukmini for the update, I am able to generate a new client secret for the Application id. And hope fully that will resolve the issue.
